# EaselJS SpriteSheet isn't responding to gotoAndPlay

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, easeljs, sprite-sheet

I'm developing a [Fez](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fez_%28video_game%29)-based HTML5 Canvas game using [EaselJS](http://www.createjs.com/#!/EaselJS) and I've found a problem, that I can't solve myself, while trying to implement *SpriteSheets* to the hero.

The problem is that I've defined three animations to my hero (`"stand"`, `"jump"` and `"run"`) and when I try to change from one animation to another using `hero.gotoAndPlay("run")` or `hero.gotoAndStop("stand")` the animations don't change, change but show the first frame only ***or*** change to the wrong animation.

Can someone help me? What I'm doing wrong and how can I fix it? Thanks.

**Here's the relevant JavaScript code I'm using to create the hero Sprite:**

```
var data = {
     images: ["http://i.imgur.com/M0GmFnz.png"],
     frames: {width:34, height:46},
     animations: {
         stand:0,
         run:[0,12,true,0.25],
         jump:13
     }
 };
var spriteSheet = new createjs.SpriteSheet(data);
var hero = new createjs.Sprite(spriteSheet, "stand");
hero.offset = 4 + 1; // "+1" is important, change the first number only.
hero.regX = hero.offset + 2;
hero.regY = hero.offset;
hero.width = 34 - (hero.offset*2) - 12;
hero.height = 46 - (hero.offset*2);
hero.x = 0;
hero.y = 0;
hero.jumping = true;
stage.addChild(hero);
```

**And the code I'm using to change the animation:**

```
if(!left && !right){ // User isn't pressing left arrow or right arrow
    hero.gotoAndStop("stand");
}else{
    hero.gotoAndPlay("run");
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/TiagoMarinho/QW2Qn/)

[**Official Site**](http://EscherParkour.com/InsaneJS.Nightly)

Comment: Are you constantly calling gotoAndStop, like on a tick or something? This will constantly set the sprite to the first frame of the animation.

Comment: Yes, I'm calling the function inside a tick. There's a way to get the actual animation that's being played in a instance?

Comment: I've tried using `function changeAnimation(obj1, frameOrAnimation){ if(obj1.animation != frameOrAnimation){obj1.animation = frameOrAnimation; obj1.gotoAndPlay(frameOrAnimation);}}` and then `if(!left && !right){ changeAnimation(hero, "stand");}else{changeAnimation(hero, "run");}` and it worked, but when I try to use the jump animation if just don't change. Here's the updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TiagoMarinho/QW2Qn/1/

Comment: I've tried using gotoAndStop instead of gotoAndPlay too. Nothing happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are calling `gotoAndStop` or `gotoAndPlay` in a tick (or similar) then it will constantly reset to the first frame. You have to ensure you only call these functions one time when the animation changes.

A good way to set this up is to store the current animation, store it, and only change it up if the animation changes. Something like:

```
var animation;
if(!left && !right){ // User isn't pressing left arrow or right arrow
    animation = "stand";
}else{
    animation = "run";
}
if (currentAnimation != animation) {
    hero.gotoAndStop(animation); 
}
```

This is just an example, but should give you an idea. You should only call these methods one time to kick off an animation.

Comment: Yeah that's what I've tried but when I do the same thing with the "jump" animation it simply doesn't work, like there's no "jump" animation defined.

Comment: **Oops!** Problem solved. I forgot to add an `if(hero.jumping == false){changeAnimation("stand");}` so the animation was changing twice per frame, from "stand" to "jump" to "stand" again. Thank you for providing information about gotoAndPlay inside a ticker. :)